# How to apply Three.js shaders to nodes

Tags: three.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-viewer

I'm trying to apply the shaders from the [shaderLib](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderLib.js) but most of them either turn the node to complete white or black. Only the `normal` shader seem to work.

This is how I apply it:

```
const shader = THREE.ShaderLib.depth;
const uniforms = shader.uniforms;
const material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  fragmentShader: shader.fragmentShader,
  vertexShader: shader.vertexShader,
  uniforms
})

this._viewer.impl.matman().addMaterial(
  data.name, material, true)
```

And set the material of the fragment with:

```
function setMaterial(fragIds, material) {

    const fragList = this._viewer.model.getFragmentList()

    this.toArray(fragIds).forEach((fragId) => {

      fragList.setMaterial(fragId, material)
    })

    this._viewer.impl.invalidate(true)
  }
```

Just like in this example: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-viewer-custom-shaders-part-1

I also tried to add colors to the uniforms like that example but it didn't help.

Any ideas why they don't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comment, Forge Viewer is using a privately owned `three.js`, and its' `WebGLRender` didn't implement all functionalities as `three.js`, either. So, it might not support all functions in the `three.js`.

To identify what happened to this case, you can consider providing a reproducible case demonstrating that, I will gladly pass it to our dev team. Those following items should be in the reproducible case:

1. A short exact description of what you are trying to achieve. The behavior you observe versus what you expect, and why this is a problem.
2. A complete yet minimal sample source model to run a test in.
3. A complete yet minimal `Forge app` that can be run and debugged with a simple procedure to analyze its behavior lives in the sample model.
4. A complete yet minimal `three.js app` that can be run and demonstrated the shader effect you want. **Note. Forge Viewer is using r71 `three.js`.**
5. Detailed step-by-step instructions for reproducing the issue, e.g. which element to pick, what command to launch etc.

If your reproducible case could not be posted here publicly, please send it to the `forge.help@autodesk.com` and `remove sensitive data or information before you send`.

======== Old response

Could you provide more detail for further debugging, please?

It seems to works fine on my side. Here are my test codes. It's tested on the Forge RCDB (https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io/database?id=57efaf0377c8eb0a560ef467).

```
var shader = THREE.ShaderLib.depth;
var uniforms = shader.uniforms;
var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  fragmentShader: shader.fragmentShader,
  vertexShader: shader.vertexShader,
  uniforms
})

NOP_VIEWER.impl.matman().addMaterial( 'ShaderLabDepth', material, true );

var sel = NOP_VIEWER.getSelection();

var fragList = NOP_VIEWER.model.getFragmentList();
var it = NOP_VIEWER.model.getData().instanceTree;
it.enumNodeFragments( sel[0], function( fragId ) {
  fragList.setMaterial( fragId, material )
});

NOP_VIEWER.impl.invalidate( true );
```

And Its' result is like this. Did it what you want?
[image]

Comment: It's completely white, I want it to keep its previous color, is this even possible?

Comment: Sorry, it's out of my league. I have no idea what the `THREE.ShaderLib.depth` did. Forge Viewer is using a private owned `three.js`, so it might not support every thing of the `three.js`.

Comment: Do you know who in Autodesk know how to work with shaders in the viewer or implement shaders for the viewer?

Comment: No, I have no idea about it, but you can consider providing a reproducible case to me, I will gladly pass it to our dev team. I've updated the answer to describe what a reproducible case should have, thanks.

Comment: You basically already reproduced it in the viewer. In the end I want a shader that will draw a line between every vertex of the node, like here: http://homepages.loria.fr/BLevy/GEOGRAM/geobox.html or here: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_wireframe, the last link doesn't work in the viewer though.

Comment: For wireframe, you can take a look the extension `Autodesk.Viewing.Wireframes` in the v2.16 viewer. Basic usage is:

`viewer.loadExtension( 'Autodesk.Viewing.Wireframes', null ).then( ( ext ) => { ext.activate(); } ); `

Comment: Or, check this:
https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/07/accessing-mesh-information-with-the-view-data-api.html

Comment: When I try to load it like you said in the viewer I get that it wasn't found. Where should I bring it from (I'm on 2.16.1)? And this one: https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/07/accessing-mesh-information-with-the-view-data-api.html is making the scene too slow because it adds too many objects to it.

Comment: OK I found the wireframes extension. Let me check it.